# Is intelligent life possible at temperatures as low as -190°C?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, creature-design

I am creating a planet where life exists on big islands of frozen methane around the poles. I did some research: from what I understand, methane freezes around -180°C, so I wanted it to be -190°C (this is because I don't want it to melt during summer).

Is intelligent life possible at temperatures this low?

Comment: "Could life be possible given x" will always be answered either with "we don't know" or "yes, we know an organism that survives there". Life and biochemistry is extremely complex, I dare say the most complex thing humanity has faced yet, nobody can make up an organism with a different chemistry behind it. It could be anything. You can even see an intelligent machine as a lifeform, I'm pretty sure you can make it work under those conditions, so why would anything else be impossible? The question is: What issues do you want solved before you think it's believable?

Comment: Unrelated 2nd comment: Check out Stephen Hawking's Into the Universe-series. I think he explores the possibility of life existing at around those temperatures in there. The step towards intelligent life, well, whatever. Nobody can say you are wrong because it's so complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have to stretch the meaning of "intelligent life". The energy levels at 80 K are pretty low but not zero, so you *could* have some kind of chemical system.

Would that system be complex enough to support life?

We're not even all that sure about what life *is*, but it looks quite likely that it involves *complexity*. At least the kind of life that evolved itself until now. Just like computers, you need a certain number of types of logic gates and connections before "electronics" might become "computing".

Going cold-wards, the chemistry would be much simpler than ours (the number of possible reactions between chemicals starts from zero at absolute zero, increases as the available energy exceeds the activation energy of more and more chemicals, reaches a peak somewhere, then falls off again as the ambient energy level at higher temperatures exceeds the stability of most substances).

Would the chemistry become so simple that a *bio*chemistry isn't possible?

At least in theory, [what you lose in configurational complexity you might compensate for with speed and *spatial* complexity](https://xkcd.com/505/), provided you kept above the unknown "sufficient basic complexity" threshold - a sort of Turing-completeness for chemistry that turns it into viable *bio*chemistry (thanks to @Raditz_35 for pointing this out).

Your sub-zero beings would probably need to be huge and sluggish, moving at a (literally) glacial pace. They would be weaker and would almost surely need a much lower gravity.

At higher temperatures than yours, you could try using ammonia instead of water and still get a "earth-like" biochemistry, in that ammonia is also polar and has comparatively high latent heat. Hal Clement, among others, experimented with that idea (I think that Mesklin, Tenebra and Enigma-88 all have some lower-temperature biochemistry going on).

At lower temperatures, the biochemistry would be completely different and I wouldn't even try to describe it. Liquid methane, ethane and other hydrocarbons are not as good as water or ammonia because they're not polar substances, but I wouldn't try going into the gory details: most readers wouldn't be able (or happy) to follow them, and unless you're into cold (bio)chemistry, those that could would probably be irked by the inevitable errors.

Answer (score 4):

Life as we know it is based on water. Water is used as solvent for carrying on the gazillions of chemical reactions involved in what we call life.

Water freezes at $0^o$C, or somewhere lower if something is solved into it. This means that once water is frozen there is no way to have those reaction take place.

No life related reactions = no life.

You might object: what about a form of life not based on water but on methane? Again, solid phase reaction are normally slower than liquid phase, so if any life was possible based on methane, it would suffer.

Comment: @Raditz_35, only those reactions used for life

Comment: I don't know what that means, but that doesnt mean it's wrong, so whatever

Answer (score 1):

One question to ask, does the life need to evolve there?

For a robotic/AI life, a frozen planet might actually be desirable as it could allow greater processing power and more efficient cooling.

Answer (score 0):

We aren’t sure the definition of intelligence yet, but if the Turing Hypothesis is true (that human intellect is equivalent to a sufficiently complex Turing Machine) then, yes, intelligent life is possible at those temps. Turing complete operations have been demonstrated in ridiculously simple systems with very low energy requirements. The thoughts might be realllllly slow, but it seems possible.

Answer (score 0):

Could human intelligent life survive -190C?

Intelligent life does not need to wear a Speedo outside on your cold planet.  It will do what it needs to do to survive.  The easiest way to have intelligent life on your cold planet is to have whatever sort of intelligent life suits your story, and then have it use its intelligence to survive on your cold planet.  Your intelligences can be from somewhere else, and they reside on the planet for their reasons.  They have technology they use to stay warm.

Or not.  I could imagine that an intelligence based on electricity might find very low temperature situations / superconductivity conducive to their kind of life.

Answer (score 0):

In the Orion's Arm universe, there is a methane-ethane based species called the Muuh.  They have ice ships made from comets.  They are slow, but then the Muuh are slow beings.  Here's a write-up for the Muuh Ice Ships for you to peruse:

http://www.orionsarm.com/eg-article/49773331d6471

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Bill! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. Have fun!

Comment: :-)  Welcome to worldbuilding, Bill!  While clever, I suspect the OP is looking for an actual scientific analysis and not simply another fictional species.  Cheers!